# call a function from within eventListener

Tags: reactjs, xmlhttprequest

I want to call a function from within the eventListener

```
I get this error : 
TypeError: this.foo is not a function
```

I understand that **this** is the `xhr` itself and not the class that wraps both function.

How can I call `foo` from within the `eventListener` callback?

```
createStripeUser = async (code) => {

    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.withCredentials = true;

    xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
             this.foo(this.responseText)
        }
    });

    xhr.open("POST", "https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token");
    xhr.send(data);
}
foo  = (data ) => {
    console.log(data)
}
```

Comment: Is `foo` defined *inside* the `createStripeUser` function?

Comment: it's defined in the class that wraps both functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want access this from outside you need to use () => {} instead of function() {} in readyStateChange callback.

```
createStripeUser = async (code) => {

const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", () => {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
         this.foo(xhr.responseText)
    }
});

xhr.open("POST", "https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token");
xhr.send(data);

foo  = (data ) => {
    console.log(data)
}
```

i don't know your code is a class or not. but if it not, just call foo(xhr.responseText) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You must use a alias for this in callback for xhr like this:

```
const that=this;
xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
         that.foo(this.responseText)
    }
});
```